# kademlia closest good nodes won't intersect enough between two requests

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

working on bep44 implementation, i use the defined kademlia algorithm to find the closest good node given an hash id.

Using my program i do `go run main.go -put "Hello World!" -kname mykey -salt foobar2 -b public` and get the value stored over a hundred nodes (good).

Now, when i run it multiple consecutive times, the sets of ip which are written by the put requests poorly intersects.

It is a problem as when i try to do a get request, the set of ips queried does not intersect with the put set, so the value is not found.

In my tests i use the public dht bootstrap node

```
        "router.utorrent.com:6881",
        "router.bittorrent.com:6881",
        "dht.transmissionbt.com:6881",
```

When i query the nodes, I select the 8 closest nodes (`nodes := s.ClosestGoodNodes(8, msg.InfoHash())`), which usually end up in a list of ~1K queries after a recursive traversal.

In my understanding, storing addresses of the info hash in the dht table is deterministic given the status of the table. As i m doing consecutive queries i expect the table to change, indeed, but not that much.

How does it happen the store nodes set does not intersect ?

Comment: my implementation is built on top of https://github.com/anacrolix/dht, all the kadmelia implementation is provided by anacrolix, i want to believe it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since BEP44 is an extension it is only supported by a subset of the DHT nodes, which means the iterative lookup mechanism needs to take support into account when determining whether the set of closest nodes is stable and the lookup can be terminated.

If a node returns a `token`, `v` or `seq` field in in a get response then it is eligible for the closest-set of a read-only *get*.

If a node returns a `token` then it is eligible for the closest-set for a *get* that will be followed by *put* operation.

So your lookup may home in on a set of nodes in the keyspace that is closest to the target ID but not eligible for the operations in question. As long as you have candidates that are closer than the best known eligible contacts you have to continue searching. I call this perimeter widening, as it conceptually broadens the search area around the target.

Additionally you also need to take error responses or the absence of a response into account when performing `put` requests. You can either retry the node or try the next eligible node instead.

I have written down some [additional constraints](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/master/docs/sanitizing-algorithms.rst) that one might want to put on the closest set in lookups for robustness and security reasons in the documentation of my own DHT implementation.

> which usually end up in a list of ~1K queries after a recursive traversal.

This suggests something is wrong with your lookup algorithm. In my experience a lookup should only take somewhere between 60 and 200 udp requests to find its target if you're doing a lookup with concurrent requests, maybe even fewer when it is sequential.

[Verbose logs](https://gist.github.com/the8472/d49f6797873cbd3c4bc29b71066bd712) of the terminal sets to eyeball how the lookups make progress and how much junk I am getting from peers have served me well.

> In my tests i use the public dht bootstrap node

You should write your routing table to disk and reload it from there and only perform bootstrapping when none of the persisted nodes in your RT are reachable. Otherwise you are wasting the bootstrap nodes' resources and also waste time by having to re-populate your routing table first before performing any lookup.

Comment: - I used the public bootstrap nodes for my test because in future i assume i ll have a client, a reader, which will also start from nowhere, so its routing table can t match the one from the writer. - During the recursive search, it always ends somewhere with no more peers to query, the 1k i observed, i m thinking to restart it from the 8th closest node, but you talked about only 200 peers, i m confused about the structure of the table and the numbers of possible peers for a given data. - Does the starting point in the dht influence the results ? - Thanks for all observations.

Comment: "Does the starting point in the dht influence the results" - generally no, it's just one big network and results should converge from any starting point, it's more a matter of efficiency

Comment: to let you know, i fixed the number of simultaneous outgoing requests (8), and the total number of queries is down to 40 / 150 (depends). but i m still blocked for the moment. Does the log format you quoted have a visualizer ?

Comment: No visualizer, I haven't needed one so far. DOT file output to visualize the traversed nodes from routing table to terminal set would certainly be cool. But the main point of my answer is the termination conditions anyway.

Comment: this peer quality question is a big issue. I m doing a get=>put=>get sequence to check, and only a very few nodes respond with a good reply. Some won t return Sign/K, some won t return V.

Comment: Well, if there are additional questions I think you should open a new one, the comment format is not well-suited for such a complex topic